# Traefik Lets encrypt and https redirection does not work without custom http challenge request exclusion

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

Here is what I want with traefik:

- https redirection
- let's encrypt ssl certificate generation
- for a brand new domain

Here is what happens

- Traefik makes a request to create a new certificate for a domain using http challenge
- Let's encrypt makes request to domain name for http challenge
- traefik redirects http to https
- there is not yet a certificate created
- certificate creation fails

So what I need is some way to exclude the http challenge from let's encrypt from the http to https redirection but I cannot find out which version traefik. I have checked debug logs but the http challenge url isn't logged.

here's the logs

```
time="2020-10-21T14:55:01Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] [my.domain.com] acme: Obtaining bundled SAN certificate"

TLS Challenge Present temp certificate for my.domain.com" providerName=acme

time="2020-10-21T14:55:17Z" level=debug msg="TLS Challenge CleanUp temp certificate for my.domain.com" providerName=acme
time="2020-10-21T14:55:17Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Deactivating auth: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/137315186"
time="2020-10-21T14:55:17Z" level=debug msg="legolog: [INFO] Unable to deactivate the authorization: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/137315186"
time="2020-10-21T14:55:17Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"my.domain.com\": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [my.domain.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[my.domain.com] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem), url: \n" routerName=sdlc-sdlc-hub-https-949014c8fdb9352a2ed9@kubernetescrd rule="Host(`my.domain.com`)" providerName=default.acme
```

The logs indicate that there is supposed to be a temporary certificate used for the challenge but it apparently does not actually work.

If I remove the https redirection for a new domain then re-add it, it works fine, but that is not a great solution if you're trying to automate things.